# What type of codes begins a class like this @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { *[class="NameOfClassHere"]

Tags: html, css, class

I came across this while looking something up for media queries.  always like learning new things and couldn't find anywhere on the net to explain this type of markup.  this is from Expedia's responsive web design shown by litmus.

https://litmus.com/scope/z1xdodxbzane

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    *[class="FlexWidth100"]{width:100% !important; height:auto!important; line-height:normal!important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically

```
*[class="FlexWidth100"]
```

is just same with

```
.FlexWidth100
```

selector

Comment: Thank you... But why would someone write it the long way?

Comment: And that * operator is a bad practice because it has it's performance penalties. It's really bad to do that on CSS for mobile apps.

Comment: it's the same. because the selector he used is class="FlexWidth100" this means it's for a element with class attribute of "FlexWidth100". I would agree with you if the selector is class*="FlexWidth100"

Comment: @AllanChua Nice catch, but please note that in this case, `*.class` is as the same as `.class` in term of performance.

Comment: `.FlexWidth100` is not the same as `*[class="FlexWidth100"]`. It is the same as `*[class~="FlexWidth100"]`. i.e.`*[class="FlexWidth100"]` matches the element if FlexWidth100 is the only class of the element, while `.FlexWidth100` matches if FlexWidth100 is any class of the element.

Answer (score 0):

`*` or called as **wildcard** in CSS. This is use for select all elements within the DOM.

So basically, your code will target all elements with class `FlexWidth100` in the DOM and apply

```
{width:100% !important; height:auto!important; line-height:normal!important;}
```

when the screen's width is less than or equal to `600px`

Comment: if this is the same as this .FlexWidth100 why would one write it the other way?

Comment: But why is it selected by attribute?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew There is no difference, just to make it's easier for author to understand or manage in my opinion

Comment: thanks that answers that.  sorry I can't give an upvote I dont' have any myself.  lol

Answer (score 0):

It's a css selector which targets all element on the .html page with the class .FlexWidth100.

This is a responsive cascading style sheet, that basically says the following in plain english:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
Target all screen media (laptop screen, desktop screens, smartphones and tablets
 screens)
Then it says, if and only if the max width of the webpage is 600px, then apply
the following styles, such as {width:100% !important; height:auto!important; 
line-height:normal!important;}
```

You can add any styles you want under there, such as:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

*[class="FlexWidth100"]{color: green;}
```

This technique is generally used to target screens with different sizes; you might not want to write a single style sheet for every media type or screen size; you write one style sheet then, within that same style sheet, you specify different styles for different media types and screen sizes. 
So, when I am looking at your website from a desktop, it looks one way, but when I look at the same website, from a mobile device for instance, it looks a different way.

Hope that helps also, try looking at Facebook from your desktop or laptop, then look at it on your mobile device and you'll see that it looks different.

Finally, to see if a site is using a responsive style sheet, look at it from a wide screen, like desktop, then hold one corner of the browser and slowly re-size the browser window to a smaller screen size, and you'll see different styles being applied to that webpage instantly only if that site is using a responsive style sheet.

Hope this helps mate!

Comment: Seem like you don't understand what OP's asking

Comment: I thought he didn't understand that type of markup and I tried to explain it to him in the best way I understand it. Sorry if I completely deviated from his question but it seems a bit relevant to his question wouldn't you think so?